# java: bad operand types for binary operator '<'

Tags: java

today guys i was doing some coding in java. i was creating a game following a tutorial. ut i found this error:

```
package net.mcreborn.fs;

import java.util.Random;

public class Render2 extends Render1
{
    public Render1 render;

    public void Render1()
    {
        render = new Render1();

        Random ra = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < render.pixels; i++)
        {
            render.pixels[i] = ra.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public void render()
    {
        draw(render, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

in `for(int i = 0; i < render.pixels; i++)` there is i(int) and render.pixels(int[]). But i see that i can't use '<'. so how i can change it? i can't change the variable type because it will give more errors.

that's the pixels variable declaration code:

```
package net.mcreborn.fs;

public class Render1
{
    public final int[] pixels;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `render.pixels` to `render.pixels.length`.

By the way, you need to allocate the `pixels` property, otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException` at runtime, as it is `null` by default.